# Ubuntu 13.04 Slow LAN download

Tags: networking, download-speed

I have problem with downloading file between Ubuntu 13.04 and network share on windows 7. When i uploading file from Ubu to Win7 everything is ok, but in other way when downloading from Win7 speed is around 30-40kB/s. Thats sad... Anyone solved this issue ?

Thx for Any help

Comment: This question is about slow download speeds on Windows, there for off topic. " but in other way when downloading from Win7 speed is around 30-40kB/s. " direct quote from the question.

Answer (score 0):

...Maybe i wrote little wrong.... "When i downloading from Win 7 i mean  sitting on my computer with ubuntu 13.04 and downloading by the LAN a files from computer with windows 7... all thing are when are trying download on Ubuntu any files by LAN speed is around 30-40 kB/s... this is the core of problem :((((